# Toshiba A505 Laptop looses all settings upon reboot

Tags: 11.04, configuration, settings

Removed W7 and Installed 11.04
I had tried the Live CD before committing to do a full install and everything worked fine. All the problem issues were never a problem because it worked out of the box.

After the install and setting the user configuration I allowed the dist-upgrade and of coarse did all the little tweaks, as I wanted to get the desktop "just right".

It was perfect until I rebooted the first time, after setting up the desktop. 
Now ALL the configuration is gone. Once more I resort to make the desktop perfect and usable. Again, after reboot, those settings/configuration is lost.

EDIT: Default configuration, no separated "/" "/home" just installed all to one partition.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is this just with settings, or all files? Say, if you put something on your desktop is it still there when you reboot?

Comment: Its not affecting files themselves. It is affecting links. So if I make a shortcut from my /home/USER/some_file to the desktop its gone on reboot.

Comment: That's a stumper. What you might try doing is backing up your home folder, if possible, and doing a clean install of 11.10. Make sure you set the same username as before and then migrate your home folder back to the new install. Beyond that I'm afraid without examining your box I can't be of much help.

Comment: I think the problem resides in the .HIDDEN folders somewhere.

Comment: True, settings are generally stored in "hidden" dot files/folders. But he's saying even .desktop files (shortcuts) are getting erased. It's very odd. I've seen cases where people use the same partition for multiple installations of Linux (which is a bad idea and could cause things like this - kind of), but he makes no mention of his setup.

Comment: As far as the set up on the Laptop. It is a default installation. No additional partitions for /home were used. I was wondering about this too. Because my Desktop Box IS partitioned with /root /home /extended and such and it doesn't have the issues like the Toshiba does. BTW I used the same Ubuntu ISO for both.

Comment: Can you add your /etc/fstab to the question. Also, did you use an encrypted home folder?

Comment: When available I can post it. No encryption was done. I think I am going to try a different release to diag the issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the .config folder corrupted